# Why is my simple JS script returning a bug?

Tags: javascript, debugging

If maryGames is set as presented here she wins. But if 97 is changed to 7 the code returns no if statements as true a part from draw which there isn't in this case. Help would be greatly appreciated :)

```
var jGames, mGames, maryGames;

jGames = (89 + 120 + 103) / 3;
mGames = (116 + 94 + 123) / 3;
maryGames = (97 + 134 + 105) / 3;

if (jGames > mGames && jGames > maryGames) {
  console.log("John wins with " + jGames);
} else if (mGames > jGames && mGames > mGames) {
  console.log("Marc wins with " + mgames);
} else if (maryGames > jGames && maryGames > mGames) {
  console.log("Mary Wins the game with " + maryGames);
} else {
  console.log("Draw");
}
```

Comment: `} else if (mGames > jGames && mGames > mGames)` this line is always false

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing it out, have found it just a bit earlier. Sometimes you can look at code for 10 minutes and be like what the hell there is no error ! But even on a snippet like this there can always be :)

Answer (score 0):

```
if (jGames > mGames && jGames > maryGames) {
  console.log("John wins with " + jGames);
} else if (mGames > jGames && mGames > mGames) {
  console.log("Marc wins with " + mgames);
} else if (maryGames > jGames && maryGames > mGames) {
  console.log("Mary Wins the game with " + maryGames);
} else {
  console.log("Draw");
}
```

In this case `else if (mGames > jGames && mGames > mGames) {`
should have been `else if (mGames > jGames && mGames > maryGames) {`

Answer (score 0):

```js
var jGames, mGames, maryGames;

jGames = (89 + 120 + 103) / 3;
mGames = (116 + 94 + 123) / 3; 
maryGames = (7 + 134 + 105) / 3;

if (jGames > mGames && jGames > maryGames) {
    console.log("John wins with " + maryGames);
} else if (mGames > jGames && mGames > maryGames) {
    console.log("Marc wins with " + mGames);
} else if (maryGames > jGames && maryGames > mGames) {
    console.log("Mary Wins the game with " + maryGames);
} else {
    console.log("Draw");
}
```